# Spring 3.2 bean with constructor fails to initialize because of an injected property using @Required

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo, spring-webflow

In a Spring 3.2 project, I am bootstraping a service bean which has an injected property. The property is injected using @Required @Value(...) from a property file. I am sure the property file is being recognozed well by the spring context though.

Please check the service class below:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {  
    private String aURIString;
    @Required 
    @Value("${someUrl}") 
    public void setaURIString(String aURIString) {
        this.aURIString = aURIString;
    }    
    private URI oamURI;
    public SomeService() throws Exception {
        super();
        try {
            oamURI = new URI(aURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new Exception("URISyntaxException created while creating a URI instance for url= "+aURIString);
        }
    }
}
```

Also please find the Configuration Class below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({ "classpath:filter.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.someOrg.SomePrj"  })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

As well as the property file "filter.properties"

```
someUrl=http://www.google.com
```

When I test using the following test file

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})
public class RestTemplateTest {
    @Resource
    private SomeService someService;    
    @Test
    public void testService() {
    }   
}
```

I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at     org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someService' defined in file [C:\CVS_Checkouts\someSpace\SomePrj\target\classes\com\someOrg\SomePrj\SomeService\SomeService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.someOrg.SomePrj.SomeService.SomeService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.someOrg.SomePrj.SomeService.SomeService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.someOrg.SomePrj.SomeService.SomeService.<init>(SomeService.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 43 more
```

In the Service class, when I replace the line:

```
private String aURIString;
```

with the line

```
private String aURIString = "www.google.com"
```

it works fine though!

It, also, works fine and the @Required property is injected from the properties file if I empty the constructor and take the line:

```
oamURI = new URI(aURIString);
```

to a member method instead of the constructor

I need the @Required property in the constructor though!!!!!

Can somebody tell a means to make sure that the context injects the @Required property before calling the @Service class constructor, so it is available when the service constructor is called by the spring context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to make value injected via setter available in constructor.

You can:

- Use constructor injection instead:

  ```
  @Autowired
  public SomeService(@Value("${someUrl}") String aURIString) throws Exception { ... }
  ```
- Use `@PostConstruct` instead of constructor for initialization code that depends on injected values:

  ```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() throws Exception { ... }
  ```
- Convert injected value in a setter instead of doing it in constructor:

  ```
  @Required 
  @Value("${someUrl}") 
  public void setaURIString(String aURIString) throws Exception {
      try {
          oamURI = new URI(aURIString);
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
          throw new Exception("URISyntaxException created while creating a URI     instance for url= "+aURIString);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer